# Crontab did not run as desired

Tags: python, macos, cron

I set crontab but nothing happened,

```
crontab -l
03 04-22 * * * python /me/radio_alarm.py
```

What's the reason, the command works as intended on Linux.

Comment: What kind of self-debugging have you done? What logs have you checked?

Comment: I cannot find a log about crontab @DeepSpace

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the script stdout and stderr:

```
03 04-22 * * * python /me/radio_alarm.py > log.txt 2>&1
```

And then check in log.txt, whats the error.

for crontab log, look into **/var/log/cron**

Comment: This should be a comment